# why my test running unsuccessfully in second case

Tags: c#, testing

```
[Test]
public void AddTwoBookForEachUser()
{
  int userOneWishlish = 69;
  int userTwoWishlish = 70;

  for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
  {
    var request = new RestRequest($"/wishlists/{userOneWishlish}/books/{i}", 
    Method.POST);
    var response = _restClient.Execute(request);
    Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessful);
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
  {
    var request = new RestRequest($"/wishlists/{userTwoWishlish}/books/{i}", 
    Method.POST);
    var response = _restClient.Execute(request);
    Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessful);
 }
}
```

I have this two almost same for loops. I have to send API request to the base. This is my endPoint (/wishlists/{wishlistsId}/books/{bookId} }. I got wishlistsId and List of bookId (They are 20 books) and I need to send just 2 books for each user. The idea is with this for loop to send two different books for each user. In this case everything working well. But when I try to make it like separate method doesn't run it.

```
public void SendTwoBooksForEachUser(int userWishlist, int[] bookId)
{
  var restClient = new RestClient();

  for (int i = 1; i < bookId.Length; i++)
  {
    var request = new 
    RestRequest($"/wishlists/{userWishlist}/books/{bookId[i]}", 
    Method.POST);
    var response = restClient.Execute(request);
    Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessful);
  }
}
```

After I call this method

```
public void AddTwoBookForEachUser()
{
   AddBooksForUser(new int[] { 1, 2 }, userOneWishlish);
}
```

And show me that response its been unsuccessfully

Comment: Please, spend some time to format code in your question

Comment: Well..., for one thing you're calling your `AddBooksForUser(int, int[])` method wrong. The example you show does call it like it was defined as `AddBooksForUser(int[], int)`. So that code - apart from being incomplete - wouldn't even compile. Is this really what you're using?

Comment: Please provide a selfcontained example, if at all possible. At least provide the _exact_ error message (possibly including stacktrace) that you get.